# Java, Spring Tests, how do I configure logging normally defined in web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

I have the following defined for my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("/App/webapp")
@ContextConfiguration({
        "classpath:/config/AConfig.xml",
        "classpath:/config/BConfig.xml",
        "classpath:/config/CConfig.xml",
        "classpath:/config/DConfig.xml"
})
public class MyTests{
    ...
}
```

In web.xml I use the same configuration plus additional configuration, for instance to configure filters and listeners. How can I enable these when doing tests?

It would be great if Spring just used the same **web.xml** but I guess that might not be an option.

I have this defined in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/config/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Is there a way to configure logging from a a contextConfig.xml ( bean definition ) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codebyexample.info/2012/03/31/how-log4j-and-junit-became-friends/

that may be helpful, in particular the part where the author does:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(someAppender)
```

You should be able to access Logger.getRootLogger() and configure it there.
If you want to use the properties file, you can do:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("/config/log4j.properties");
```

[How to configure log4j.properties for SpringJUnit4ClassRunner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570072/how-to-configure-log4j-properties-for-springjunit4classrunner)

or manually configure it like:

```
Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
rootLogger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(
       new PatternLayout("%-6r [%p] %c - %m%n")));
```

These configurations should be done once before all classes are run, though I don't think they harm too much if you do them in a @Before method.

Comment: I opted for the PropertyConfigurator, however, it requires a full absolute path.

Comment: You might be able to use the syntax classpath:/a/b/c

Comment: If you're using maven, you might need to make sure the file is in the test resources folder (or src resources folder). have a look at: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/26798-classpath-context-xml-with-file-system-properties  (which refers to: docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092713/using-classpath-in-spring